# Best polynomial-time approximation factor for NP-optimization problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness

Let us say that a function $f(n)$ is the **best approximation factor** for an NP-optimization problem, if both of the following hold:

1. There exist a polynomial-time algorithm $A,$ and an integer $n_0$, such that $A$ provides an $f(n)$-approximation for the NP-optimization problem for every instance with size $n\geq n_0$. (Note: the role of $n_0$ is merely to treat potentially deviant small instances, which might make the function "ugly.")
2. There is no polynomial-time $(1-o(1))f(n)$ approximation, unless $P=NP$.

A classic example where such a best approximation is known is the SET COVER problem (for a summary and references see its Wikipedia page): the Greedy Algorithm provides an $\ln n$ approximation, but there is no  $(1-o(1))\ln n$ approximation, unless $P=NP$.

**Questions:**

1. Which are some other interesting NP-optimization problems for which a best approximation factor, along with its realizing algorithm, are known?
2. Are there any counterexamples, i.e., NP-optimization problems, for which such a best approximation cannot exist, unless $P=NP$?

Comment: The statement isn't completely formally defined, but it's likely that any NP-hard problem with a PTAS will satisfy most formal restatements the second criterion.